# TableViewCells width in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a cell on a tableview which doesn't go "all the way" from left-to-right of the screen.

Basically, what I need is a cell which (as usual) starts on the left side of the screen, but with a given width, creating a free space on the right.

Is there any way of doing it? I wasn't able to find any example.

Sorry for the eventually noob question, and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of the SDK this was possible using the `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:`method, however this is deprecated since 3.0, so that you should create the `UITableViewCell` using the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method.

You can access the frame of the `UITableViewCell` using the `frame` property and change it's size:

```
CGRect frame = cell.frame;
frame.size.width = 123f;
cell.frame = frame;
```

For indentation on the left side you can simply use the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:`

You can also add a specific subview to the `UITableViewCell` on the right side (an accessory view) using the accessoryView property of the cell:

```
UIView *view = ...
cell.accessoryView = view;
```

(If the value of this property is not nil, the UITableViewCell class uses the given view for the accessory view in the table view’s normal (default) state; it ignores the value of the accessoryType property. The provided accessory view can be a framework-provided control or label or a custom view. The accessory view appears in the the right side of the cell. [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/accessoryView))

Comment: Using 
CGRect frame = cell.frame;
frame.size.width = 123f;
cell.frame = frame;

and defining a background color for my cell, the cell remained the same size, despising of the values I used for its frame. Besides, resizing my cell like this would't prevent the cell separator to show it's ugly face 'till the right of the table, would it?

I tried to resize the whole view, but it made the index "shrink", and I don't want that, only the cells (and the separator).

The only way I'm seeing to do what I want is defining an image working as a separator for my cells, and define it as background.

Comment: You could also change the style of your tableview so that it uses no separators (`tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone`) and add your own separator as UIImageView as subview to the cell (`[cell addSubview:...];`).

Comment: Yes, that was what I did. And to set the cell's background of the size I want, I inserted a label in the cell, and modified it's background. It's not "clean" but it works...